# What's the replacement for Session.ReauthorizeRequest?

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-android-sdk

In the final 3.0 SDK, the class ReauthorizeRequest is gone. How can I replace the following code?

```
Session.ReauthorizeRequest request = new Session.ReauthorizeRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
request.setRequestCode(REAUTHORIZE_ACTIVITY);
request.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK);
request.setCallback(this);
session.reauthorizeForPublish(request);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are now using NewPermissionsRequest.
Check here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Session

```
Session.NewPermissionsRequest request = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
request.setRequestCode(REAUTHORIZE_ACTIVITY);
request.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK);
request.setCallback(this);
session.requestNewPublishPermissions(request);
```

Comment: can u post all code here because i have done but it ask for re-auth second time when i ask for more permission